# Java Print statement gives “cannot find symbol” Lynda tutorial

Tags: java

Java Print statement gives “cannot find symbol”

trying to compile

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printIn("Hello from Java!");
    }

}
```

and an error occured about the `System.out.PrintIn`

Comment: `System.out.printIn` has an `I` when it should have a `l`; it's `System.out.println`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch haha exactly pointed out..

Comment: Thank you i realized that after posting. That it was a simple noob error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println`, from **print line** not `printIn` with capital letter `I`.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a method "println(String)" to print string and take the cursor to the next line.
- The program has an error because "printIn()" has been used which is not a valid method name in "System.out". Hence replace "printIn()" with "println(String)".

The below program complies and runs well:

**Main.java**

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from Java!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i realized that after posting i put an "i" instead of a "l". I guess it  was a simple noob error. Thanks for your help.